# Color every row of a html table basing on its children content

Tags: jquery, html-table

How'd you print in a html page that fetches these info from a PG Database:

**A**. A table with many rows, where each of them have 1 or more children

**B**. and these children are extracted from a SQL using a non-pk ID, where 1-parentID n-childID

**C**. and colour the parent row with the color of the children where:
IF 2 children, both of them have "ACK=1" -> parent is 1 (COLOR green).
IF 2 children, 1 is ACK=1 and the other ACK=-1, the parent is -1 (COLOR red).

In HTML / PHP / javaApplet / Javascript / Jquery -> I am not interested in the language used, it will be amazing if this could work someday .

The Excel image is to show how I'd like this table to look, been trying for over a week and very poor results.

RowN-hidden is used by bootstrap's collapsible panel (or similar).

EDIT (2):

The html code of my table is:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Expand</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Identification</th>
<th>Expedition</th>
<th>Direction</th>
<th>MDN</th>
<th>ACK</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr class=parentrow>
<td>+</td>
<td>27.09.2016</td>
<td>prost</td>
<td>qwa</td>
<td>sent</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr class=childrow>
<td colspan=9><table><tr>
<td>prost 12 12 1 -1</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>

<tr class=parentrow>
<td>+</td>
<td>24.09.2016</td>
<td>wenon</td>
<td>pra</td>
<td>sent</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr class=childrow>
<td colspan=9><table><tr>
<td>wenon 32 sent 1 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>wenon 35 sent 1 1</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

**ACK and MDN of parent are not ACK and MDN of child.**

1st query will select (date,identification,expedition,direction,mdn,ack) from table 1.
2nd query will select (identification, expedition direction, mdn,ack) from table 2, where id of table 1 is like id of table 2.

the html only shows ROW1 and ROW2 in this example.
The button will open a hidden `<tr>` with the result of SQL2 (colspan=9 to match the lenght of its parent).

When the child have its ACK 1 or -1, the parent must inherits the color, not the value, because it will just be a case if their ACKs are the same.

If one of the child has a negative ACK, the parent should highlight as error (red) to focus the attention on the child, which I will open using the + button.

In the near future, children will have more values and may not have mdn, but ACK will always remain

[image]

Comment: add the html code of your table

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that your table has this html code

```
<table id="tableId">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Expand</th>
        ....
         <th>ACK</th>
        ...
      <tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>      
          <td>4</td>
             ...
          <td class="ACK">0</td>
              ...
      </tr>
      ....
   </tbody>
</table>
```

As I understood, that all ACK with 0 values will be red and with 1 value will be green right? then mark all ACK column tds, assign `class="ACK"` as above, then you can do the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ACK').each(function(index){
         var me = $(this);
         if(me.text() =='0'){
            me.closest('tr').css('background-color','red');
         }
         else if(me.text()=='1'){
            me.closest('tr').css('background-color','green');
         }
    });
});
```

Here a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hgqwx2ew/)

And if you want to compare ACK to MDN columns, ( if they were the same then green and if not then red), then you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ACK').each(function(index){
         var me = $(this);
         if(me.text() !== me.prev('td').text()){
            me.closest('tr').css('background-color','red');
         }
         else if(me.text()==me.prev('td').text()){
            me.closest('tr').css('background-color','green');
         }
    });
});
```

Here a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hgqwx2ew/1/)

Hope this will help you

Comment: This sir helped me more than I'd ever thought!
I am able to read the code, I think I can easily move into my project, only a question:  every <tr> may have one or more other <tr> as child. The child are the one that need to be coloured, the parent must only inherit the colour of the child (this is tricky for me because it is usually the other way round, where child inherits parents thing).
So, if child 1 of parent 1 is ACK 1, parent is 1- green. If child 1 of parent 2 is ACK -1, parent 2 is red even tho child 2 parent 2 is ACK 1 (green).

Comment: Post updated with html and php code, it may be incomplete but what matters now is the "shape" i tried giving it. where there is a <tr> parent and N <tr> child

Comment: sorry to remove the accepted answer. i've been trying and what you wrote, although well detailed, it does not 100% fulfills the request. Because:

`<table><thead><th></th></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class=parentrow><td></td></tr>
<tr class=childrow><td colspan=9><table>
<tr><td>ACK 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>ACK 0</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
<tr class=parentrow>[...]`

I must both color the <tr> of ACK and the <tr> parent.
I'm trying modifying your code without results, and actually this is what my question is about. Without jquery I am able already to change color of the same row of ACK

Comment: can you show a sample of what you want to get as output?

Comment: Sure! I'll be updating the post in a while, I guess I'll just replace the current image with one more clear! Thanks for your time!

Comment: why you are adding the children tr beside the parent tr? I think your should add the children inside the parent tr , so it will be like ( `<table><tr class="parent"><td> <table class="child"><tr class="childRow">...</tr></table></td></tr></table>` )

Comment: I'm updating the post, almost completed what to upload locally!
I did it because I use the collapse funtion of bootstrap, but I can not have the same ID for more <tr>, just because IDs are not meant for this.
I thought then to encapsulate the child inside a <tr id=identification> so when I hit the + button, it will collapse in/out. Not the best, but works